# d3 - help required in node

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Here's the [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/e7vLE/).

I've created this `collapsible tree layout` from this [**link**](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/tree.html).

Now everything works just fine but I wanted to add one more criteria over here.

That I do not want to expand the children based on some value either `yes` or `no`.

If the value is `no` then I do not want to expand it else I wanted to expand it.

But if I add some value the `name` in the data. This chart doesn't work at all.

Someone help me out to achieve it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are really many ways to do this. Here is one...

Set your data like this:

```
{
"name": "sublevel3",
"expand": "no", // add the yes/no property
"children": [
...
```

Then make this change in the script:

```
// Toggle children.
function toggle(d) {
    if (d.children && d.expand != "no") { // leverage the yes/no property
        d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
    } else {
        d.children = d._children;
        d._children = null;
    }
}
```

This is just a quick demo. You probably would want to set each parent node with a yes/node and make the check based on the presence of a yes:) I just set one to illustrate the point.

Here is the changed [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KB4Uw/).

Comment: Wow man. I thought that it'll be more difficult. But it easy as a pie :) Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Yes, the data-driven aspect of D3 comes to the rescue :)